# How do you turn off extra spacing between bars in a printed version of a Microsoft Project 2013 Gantt chart?

Tags: microsoft-project, gantt, microsoft-project-2013

When I am working with a project the Gantt chart is shown on screen with minimal spacing between bars. Looks great.

When I go to export, print or *Copy Picture*, the formatter leaves space for additional printed information that could be listed in the Bar Styles text formatting. *Copy Picture* is the command in Project located as a Copy option in the Task tab.

You can have text to the left, top, bottom, right and inside of the bar. In my project those fields are all blank except for the task Name to the right of the bar. The working display version takes this into account.

I would like to find an option to turn off the extra spacing when there is no text. Adjusting the Scaling in File/Print/Page Setup changes the font size as well so it really doesn't help.

In the past when I used Project 2003 I believe we used screen captures to get around the issue.

Comment: Any resolution on this?  I know exactly what you are getting at.  It's frustrating.

Comment: I never did and I haven't been back to it.  I'll look at your answer next week and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

First, please make sure you are up to date with service packs and public updates.  There were a number of "fixes" for printing issues.  Start here:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/projectsupport/p/msp13.aspx

Second - it appears as though you have two issues?  First the display of the legend - what you describe as "formatter leaves space for additional printed information that could be listed in the Bar Styles text formatting".  You can turn off the legend completely in the Page Setup dialog.  If you want to leave the legend on but suppress the display for bars you are not using - edit the Bar Style and place an asterisk (*) in front of the name of the bar you don't want to display.

As far as vertical spacing - do you have text wrapped in the Task Name field?  Earlier versions (Project 2003) didn't have text wrapping - so that may be contributing to the issue.

Comment: The legend is what prints in the footer of the document. I have no issue with that. Turning that off doesn't affect bar spacing on the print preview.  All of the bars I want to print are printing, it is just that there is blank space above and below each bar. If I change the bar style to print something above and or below the bar, that text is in that same space.

Comment: Look at the Bar Styles dialog - are all the bars in Row 1?

Comment: Yes they are. I Initially didn't understand the question.

Comment: Are you up to date with all public updates and service packs?  I cannot reproduce what you report.

Comment: It is a brand new installation from Office 365.  Windows update is current. To confirm, if you add text to the Bar Style for above and below, your bars will move further down on a printed page as I see in the Gantt view.. On mine they stay in the almost the same spot as they already had room for the text.  I'm thinking this is just normal and what people are used to seeing they don't really notice it.

Comment: Are you seeing this in Project Pro for Office 365, Project Professional (desktop), PWA, or Project Server?

Comment: Microsoft Project Pro for Office 365  Version 15.0.4737.1003

Comment: Ah, thanks.  Well, now I need to take back everything I've said.  I cannot reproduce the error in the desktop version but don't have access to the subscription version.  Sorry - I'm not sure I can be of any further help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4c2b53e2-c4bd-466d-9452-05be83c9938e/ms-project-2013-gantt-chart-view-row-height-printing-problem?forum=projectprofessional2010general

It's not obvious at all.  I had my page set-up to fit to 1 page wide and 4 tall.  Project does some weird scaling with fonts and the rows. Switch to 'Adjust to' and your formatting will instantly adjust to the way you wanted it.  The only catch is you need to manually tweak that % to get it to fit.  You won't get exact page multiple to fit (i.e. some white space on the last page) but it's close enough :)

Before and after below.  You can see how the space below the bars is gone.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Project gets stuck with extra spacing in Copy Picture.  I reduced font from 11 point to 10 point, then back to 11 point and that fixed Project spacing for me. Gantt Chart reset to default also works - but I didn't like how everything gets reset.